# Uploading image to Cloudinary with rails (no implicit conversion of nil into String) whil

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I am trying to upload a image on CDN with rails and react .

First i am sending data from react front end through formdata.
with submit function like this

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setLoading(true)
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('blog[title]',title)
        formData.append('blog[body]',body)
        formData.append('blog[image]',bannerImage)

        try{
            const response = await axios.post("/blogs",formData)
            setLoading(false)
            console.log("blog submit response", response)
            setBlogPosted(response.data.blog)
            history.push(`/blogs/${response.data.blog.id}/preview`)
            setLoading(false)
        } catch(error){
            console.log("blog not saved error",error)
        }        
    }
```

to rails backend
and the create method for the same in controller is

```rb
def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params.merge(user_id: @current_user.id))
    upload_image = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image])
    @blog.update(image: upload_image['url'])

    if authorized?
      if @blog.save
        render status: :ok,
              json: {blog: @blog , notice: "Blog Successfully created"}
      else
        errors = @blog.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        render status: :unprocessable_entity, json: {error:errors}
      end
    end
  end
```

and the console is showing the parameters which are passed as

```
Started POST "/blogs" for ::1 at 2021-09-24 19:46:01 +0530
Processing by BlogsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"blog"=>{"title"=>"<p>vjbklm;</p>", "body"=>"<p>nkml,</p>", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000eca9d98 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20210924-8588-1fxz7dp.png>, @original_filename="logo.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"blog[image]\"; filename=\"logo.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}
```

but getting error
`Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 667ms (ActiveRecord: 102.3ms | Allocations: 18933) TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):` 
i am unable to understand if the image params is passed with value shown above in parameters then why `upload_image = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image])` is getting nil value.

or what am i doing wrong , any help will be very helpful.

Comment: Since the params data is in blog['image'], shouldn't the params be params[:blog][:image] or something across those lines? When you prrint out params before line upload_image = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image]) what do you get?

Comment: Thanks a lot your comments helped me solved my problem

Comment: Glad that help!